# Disable auto formatting in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that gets the data from an XML schema which connects to a database. There are few fields that return a string instead of decimals.

Problem is that Crystal report consider this situation and converts the string to an integer. I have no idea why it converts to integer instead of a double. And I want to make sure this doesn't happen. While formatting is good, converting to integer instead of float or double makes no sense.

Is there a way to tell Crystal report to treat the string as a string alone?

Comment: "I THINK" there is an checkbox option under the Report Options menu that converts fields to default datatypes

Comment: I am editing the report file in Visual studio. I can't find any option there. What am I missing?